# How to document shell function?

Tags: bash, function, shell, documentation

I'm looking for some format to describe functions in shell scripts.
E.g. in PHP:

```
/**
 * My description
 *
 * @param string $paramOne Some extra comment for this parameter
 * @param int    $paramTwo
 * @return $this
 */
function myCoolFunc($paramOne, $paramTwo)
{
}
```

Any documentation format there?

**UPD 1** I'm not looking for some documentation processor. Just format.

It would be like this:

```
# Simple yes/no dialog question
#
# e.g.: $(dialog_yes_no 'Would like to repeat?' 'n' 3)
#
# string question
# string default
# int mistakes_count = 5
function dialog_yes_no
{
}
```

Comment: What are you intending to use to actually generate the output documentation? What do you use for php?

Comment: This is not so much a question of bash, but of the IDE you are using or the documentation processor, if that is what you are ultimately looking at.

Comment: @EtanReisner, I understand your question. So, no. Just documentation for a developer. You know, it's not easy understand to know how many parameters a function have. Which one of them has default value.

Comment: @arkascha, it may belongs to some IDE but I need no documentation processor. Just documentation format.

Comment: If the format is just for you to read then use anything you want. If it is for a tool then you need to use something the tool can understand. If the question is for you then I don't see how you expect anyone to answer it.

Comment: When in doubt, use someone else's coding standards :-) I'd recommend checking out the Google Style Guides, https://github.com/google/styleguide. Specifically, check out this Shell style guide: http://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml

Comment: Why do you ask for a special format if the comments are just for yourself to read them? Use whatever appears suitable to you! The format is only of interest if some parser / compiler has to process those comments.

Comment: @arkascha, I just used to follow formats. I don't want to think how to get it up. Different people can write it in completely different ways. :)

Comment: @criswell, yeah, Google shell coding standards work for me. I think you may post an answer with the link: http://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml?showone=Function_Comments#Function_Comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do use following format, You can start using this format, it is something similar to man/info used by unix/linux.

```
#!/bin/ksh
#================================================================
# HEADER
#================================================================
#% SYNOPSIS
#+    ${SCRIPT_NAME} [-hv] [-o[file]] args ...
#%
#% DESCRIPTION
#%    This is a script template
#%    to start any good shell script.
#%
#% OPTIONS
#%    -o [file], --output=[file]    Set log file (default=/dev/null)
#%                                  use DEFAULT keyword to autoname file
#%                                  The default value is /dev/null.
#%    -t, --timelog                 Add timestamp to log ("+%y/%m/%d@%H:%M:%S")
#%    -x, --ignorelock              Ignore if lock file exists
#%    -h, --help                    Print this help
#%    -v, --version                 Print script information
#%
#% EXAMPLES
#%    ${SCRIPT_NAME} -o DEFAULT arg1 arg2
#%
#================================================================
#- IMPLEMENTATION
#-    version         ${SCRIPT_NAME} (www.uxora.com) 0.0.4
#-    author          Michel VONGVILAY
#-    copyright       Copyright (c) http://www.uxora.com
#-    license         GNU General Public License
#-    script_id       12345
#-
#================================================================
#  HISTORY
#     2015/03/01 : mvongvilay : Script creation
#     2015/04/01 : mvongvilay : Add long options and improvements
# 
#================================================================
#  DEBUG OPTION
#    set -n  # Uncomment to check your syntax, without execution.
#    set -x  # Uncomment to debug this shell script
#
#================================================================
# END_OF_HEADER
#================================================================
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question (which doesn't have a factual answer anyway) of how to document a function. This is a nice looking template for a script header, though.

Comment: @chepner, but here is no another option to choose. :P

Comment: @Kirby You aren't required to accept any answer.